Input pattern validation for lighting textArea tag
I am trying to validate the input pattern of the lightning-textarea tag but, pattern is not directly supported in this tag.
So can anyone tell me how can I achieve this using SetCustomValidity() or reportValidity() methods.


Try something like this -- https://medium.com/salesforce-champion/lightning-web-component-custom-validations-4f4d87e119b9
But then instead of the test simply checking for a value, do a regular expression operation.  https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp
const regex = new RegExp('pattern');
const itMatches = regex.test(myString);
